# OpenGL view's transformation matrix is resetting when I rotate iPad

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cgaffinetransform

In order to adopt my game for iPad, I've scaled up my openGL view using CGAffineTransformScale. Everything works fine, but when I rotate the device, the transformation matrix is resetting and I get unscaled openGL view which takes only 1/4 of the screen. I found out that this happens when EAGLView layoutSubviews is called. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Insert your `CGAffineTransformScale` code into EAGLView `layoutSubviews` method.